# Подсчет уникальных слов с группировкой по дате

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, nlp

Есть таблица (Дата, Сообщение). Для каждого значения 'Дата'(для каждого дня) необходимо подсчитать количество уникальных слов в сообщениях. Как это реализовать в Python?

Пример данных:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
[{'Date': '21-03-2019', 'Message': 'Привет. Как ты? Что делаешь?'},
 {'Date': '21-03-2019', 'Message': 'Салют. Сижу, редактирую вопрос на stackoverflow.'},
 {'Date': '22-03-2019', 'Message': 'Привет. Ну как успехи?'},
 {'Date': '22-03-2019', 'Message': 'Привет. Не очень хорошо. Редактировал пример датасета и браузер слетел. Пришлось начинать всё сначала.'},
 {'Date': '23-03-2019', 'Message': 'Привет. Ну что в итоге? Помогли тебе?'},
 {'Date': '23-03-2019', 'Message': 'Камон, мы о stackoverflow говорим! Конечно помогли.'}}])
```

На выходе хотелось бы получить что-то в стиле:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame(
[{'Date': '21-03-2019', 'NumberOfUniqueWords': 11},
{'Date': '22-03-2019', 'NumberOfUniqueWords': 17},
{'Date': '23-03-2019', 'NumberOfUniqueWords': 13}])
```

Comment: Добавьте примеры входных данных и того, что хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть как-то так? Я сгруппировал датафрейм по дате, объединил отдельные сообщения для каждой даты в одну строку и с ней уже проводил манипуляции.

```
res = (df.groupby('Date')['Message']  # Группируем датафрейм по дате.
         .agg(' '.join)  # Объединяем сообщения в одну строку
         .str.replace(r'[.?,]', '')  # Удаляем ненужные символы
         .str.lower()  # Переводим в нижний регистр

         # Разбиваем строку на список слов, конвертируем в множество,
         # чтобы получить только уникальные слова и считаем длину множества
         .apply(lambda x: len(set(x.split())))
         .to_frame()  # Конвертируем в датафрейм
         .reset_index()  # Сбрасываем индекс
         .rename(columns={'Message': 'NumberOfUniqueWords'})
)
res
```

Результат:

```
          Date  NumberOfUniqueWords
0   21-03-2019                   11
1   22-03-2019                   17
2   23-03-2019                   13
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает отлично) отдельная благодарность за комментарии к строкам кода

Answer (score 2):

Ещё одно решение:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

def nunique_words(col):
    s = col.str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ').str.lower().str.cat(sep=' ')
    return len(set(word_tokenize(s)))


res = (df.groupby('Date')['Message']
         .agg(nunique_words)
         .reset_index(name='NumberOfUniqueWords')
```

результат:

```
In [80]: res
Out[80]:
         Date  NumberOfUniqueWords
0  21-03-2019                   11
1  22-03-2019                   17
2  23-03-2019                   13
```